# Lookup inside arrays or quick Lookup in Excel

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have two ranges

First range("D:D") in sheet(1)  starting from second row to last row, This is Lookup_values, 140.000 rows

```
x1 = Worksheets("1").range(Worksheets("1").Cells(2, "D").Address, Worksheets("1").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).value
```

Second range("A:D") in sheet(2)  starting from second row to last row, this is tabble_array, 500.000 rows

```
x2 = Worksheets("2").range(Worksheets("2").Cells(2, 4).Address, Worksheets("2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).value
```

Here i trying to look up inside arrays

```
ReDim ListBoxArrSplitToRows(1 To 4, 1 To UBound(x2, 1))
CX = UBound(x2, 2)
For ii = 2 To UBound(x1, 1)
    For i = 1 To UBound(x2, 1)
        SearchInst = x2(i, 1)
        txt = x1(ii, 1)
        If InStr(SearchInst, txt) Then
            zz = zz + 1
            For counter = 1 To 4
                ListBoxArrSplitToRows(counter, zz) = x2(i, counter)
            Next counter
        Else
        End If
    Next i

Next ii

    If zz <> 0 Then ReDim Preserve ListBoxArrSplitToRows(1 To 4, 1 To zz) Else ReDim ListBoxArrSplitToRows(0, 0): MsgBox "No matches"

Worksheets(1).Cells(2, "E").Resize(UBound(ListBoxArrSplitToRows, 2), 3) = ListBoxArrSplitToRows
```

`ii=3
Ubound(x1,1) = 136586
Ubound(x2,1) = 496369
zz=1`

How to quick lookup two large ranges, beacause that code takes 30 min to lookup values and it is too long

Comment: What is the value of `zz` when the error raises?

Comment: it is a long i just formated to looks nice

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the cause of your "Subscript out of range" error is that `zz` is greater than `UBound(x2, 1)` which makes it out of `ListBoxArrSplitToRows` bounds.

The quick fix is to move this line

```
If zz <> 0 Then ReDim Preserve ListBoxArrSplitToRows(1 To 4, 1 To zz)
```

one line higher up, i.e. before `Next i`. Though get rid of `Else ReDim ListBoxArrSplitToRows(0, 0)`; I don't know what this achieves.

Comment: Else ReDim ListBoxArrSplitToRows(0, 0) used to reset array if no matches found

Comment: I know that, but what does this achieve? Why would you do that?

Comment: if dont do that listbox will fill with empty rows